# Check if values in a column contains values other than alphabets or spaces

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following dataframe

```
ID Name
1  Ajay
2  John Doe
3  Mark2
4  Clint!
5  Username@33
```

The name column should have only alphabets or spaces. I need to filter out those rows which satisfy the condition

So, the results should be

```
ID Name
3  Mark2
4  Clint!
5  Username@33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `udf` you can use **`.rlike`** inbuilt spark function for this case.

**`[^a-zA-Z\\s+]+`** -> match all characters that are not in **`a-z and space`**

**`Example:`**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.filter(col("Name").rlike("[^a-zA-Z\\s+]+")).show()
//+---+-----------+
//| ID|       Name|
//+---+-----------+
//|  3|      Mark2|
//|  4|     Clint!|
//|  5|Username@33|
//+---+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the following working for me

```
val allowed = (('a' to 'z') ++ ('A' to 'Z')).toSet
val allowedNew = allowed + ' '
def isOrdinary(s: String) = s.forall(allowedNew.contains)
def filUDF = udf[Boolean, String](isOrdinary)
df.filter(!filUDF($"Name")).show()
```